# Organise output data according to an order

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

I would like to organise the output of the following code. Please advise on how can I procede.

```
StringStream ss;

for (i = 0; i < vecDB.size(); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < vecUser.size(); j++) {
        if (vecDB[i].AccessLevel == vecUser[j].Accesslevel) {
            ss << vecUser[j].Accesslevel << endl;
        } else if (vecDB[i].AccessLevel < vecUser[j].Accesslevel) {
            ss << vecUser[j].Accesslevel << endl;
        } else if (vecUser[j].Accesslevel < vecDBi].AccessLevel) {
            ss << vecUser[j].Accesslevel << endl;
        }
    }
}

cout << ss.str();
```

**Current Output**

```
Level0
Level3
Level2
Level4
Level0
Level0
Level1
Level4
Level2
Level3
```

**Desired Output**

```
Level0
Level0
Level0
Level1
Level2
Level2
Level3
Level3
Level4
Level4
```

Comment: Surely part of the problem here is that you output `vecUser[j].Accesslevel` no matter what the condition is before it.

Comment: `vecDBi].AccessLevel` is not valid. Post your _real_ testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your logic is messed up:

- If `vecUser[j]` == `vecDBi[i]` then output `vecUser[j].Accesslevel`
- If `vecUser[j]` < `vecDBi[i]` then output `vecUser[j].Accesslevel`
- If `vecUser[j]` > `vecDBi[i]` then output `vecUser[j].Accesslevel`
- If nothing of the above then output `vecUser[j].Accesslevel`

No matter what you always output `vecUser[j].Accesslevel`.

In other words you can replace this:

```
if (vecDB[i].AccessLevel == vecUser[j].Accesslevel) {
    ss << vecUser[j].Accesslevel << endl;
} else if (vecDB[i].AccessLevel < vecUser[j].Accesslevel) {
    ss << vecUser[j].Accesslevel << endl;
} else if (vecUser[j].Accesslevel < vecDBi].AccessLevel) {
    ss << vecUser[j].Accesslevel << endl;
}
```

with the following and still get the same result.

```
ss << vecUser[j].Accesslevel << endl;
```

I don't know what you want to achieve with this logic, but for now it's broken.

---

If you simply wish to output the strings in order then why not just sort them?

```
std::vector<std::string> sorted{std::begin(vecUser), std::end(vecUser)};
std::sort(std::begin(sorted), std::end(sorted));

for (const auto& s : sorted) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: i am autally comparing the DB table access level and the user access level and print out the tablename and the user accesselevel. For a specific table there can be different users with the same access level. Thats y the level 0 repeats again. However I would like to check and sort it acorrding to userlevel before printing it. "TblYY has user James with Acces level0". This is the message i am trying to print. So how can i sort a string and print it out.

Comment: The loop indicated above is to do the checking, however, do shorten the code, i did not display the complete sentance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code always prints vecUser[j].AccessLevel

I hope you wanted to print vecDB[i] in the last case

this can be written as

```
if(vecDB[i].Accesslevel <= vecUser[j].AccessLevel)
   ss << vecUser[j].AccessLevel << endl;
else
   ss << vecDB[i].AccessLevel << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another vector to insert the data instead of inserting into StringStream obj. Then use [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) algorithm on the vector.

Comment: It will contain a string such as "TblYY has user James with Acces level0" can it be still sorted. If I store the string a vector.

Comment: "TblYY has user James with Acces level0"
"TblEE has user Mkie with Acces level1"

Can this be still sorted.